# Sort using auxiliary fields, start and end

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, what is the best way to sort records using start and end fields in a generic way, without the need to include in the query the first record (`where start_id=3`)?

Example table:

```
+-------+----------+--------+--------+
| FK_ID | START_ID | END_ID | STRING |
+-------+----------+--------+--------+
|    77 |        1 |      9 | E      |
|    82 |        5 |      2 | A      |
|    77 |        7 |      1 | I      |
|    77 |        3 |      7 | W      |
|    82 |        9 |      5 | Q      |
|    77 |        9 |      5 | X      |
|    82 |        2 |      7 | G      |
+-------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Sorted `where FK_ID = 77`:

```
+----+---+---+---+
| 77 | 3 | 7 | W |
| 77 | 7 | 1 | I |
| 77 | 1 | 9 | E |
| 77 | 9 | 5 | X |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Sorted `where FK_ID = 82`:

```
+----+---+---+---+
| 82 | 9 | 5 | Q |
| 82 | 5 | 2 | A |
| 82 | 2 | 7 | G |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Result query sequence:

```
+-------+----------+
| FK_ID | SEQUENCE |
+-------+----------+
|    82 | QAG      |
|    77 | WIEX     |
+-------+----------+
```

Comment: How do you know `3`, `5` is the starting sequence?

Comment: To make it clear in the question is a random sequence. They are foreing keys from another table. In fact, they are table IDs with thousands of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is the most efficient way but you can try with a recursive CTE

```
WITH RECURSIVE path AS (
  SELECT * FROM myTable AS t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM myTable AS t2 WHERE t1.fk_id = t2.fk_id AND t2.end_id = t1.start_id
  ) ORDER BY start_id LIMIT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT myTable.* FROM myTable JOIN path ON path.end_id = myTable.start_id
)
SELECT fk_id,array_to_string(array_agg(string)) FROM path GROUP BY fk_id
```

Comment: Thanks @IVO, see the change I made in the question.

Comment: I updated the query but have not tested the code - it might need some tweaking